# Why last-child isn't working?

Tags: css, pseudo-class, css-selectors

I got a problem for you to solve, as you know.
I ripped off all my hair trying to figure out why the heck `last-child` isn't working.
I tried to remove `border-right` with `last-child` but for some reasons, it didn't work out.
[Here's is the link](http://jsbin.com/apuhep/3/edit)

Comment: What about it is not working? What exactly is the problem for us to solve? I also don't see any CSS OR JavaScript that uses last-child in there. That leaves this question destined to be cryptic and unanswered. ;-)

Comment: @gregpettit Ok, gona add them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector is `#countdown .num:last-child`.

Your HTML is

```
<ul ID="countdown">
  <li> <div ID="days" class="num">00</div>  <div CLASS="text">days</div>     </li>
  <li> <div ID="hours" class="num">00</div> <div CLASS="text">hours</div>    </li> 
  <li> <div ID="mins" class="num">00</div>  <div CLASS="text">minutes</div>  </li>
  <li> <div ID="secs" class="num">00</div>  <div CLASS="text">seconds</div>  </li>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

Think: is `.num` the last child of its parent? Answer: no.

Your selector should be more like `#countdown > li:last-of-type .num`, selecting `.num` inside the last `li` in `#countdown`.

Note that in this case `last-of-type` must be used rather than `last-child` because you've got that `<div class="clear"></div>`, which is invalid HTML (you can't have a `div` directly inside a `ul`).

Comment: If you really need to keep that `.clear` element, move it right after the closing `</ul>` tag. Trivial fix.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why the `last-child` is not working because in your  `#countdown` UL the `last-child` is `<div class="clear"></div>` not `LI`. So it's better to use `last-of-type`  instead of `last-child`. Like this:

```
#countdown li:last-of-type .num,
  #countdown li:last-of-type .text{
    border:0;
  }
```

Check this http://jsbin.com/apuhep/4/edit#html,live

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `ul` element, there is a `div` element after the last `li` element. This is invalid markup and may have unpredictable effects. Moreover, it probably makes browsers treat the `div` element the last child of the `ul` element.